# How can I filter on the results of a set function

Tags: postgresql

I have a function that returns a `SETOF`, and I want to filter on the set column.

Here's a minimal reproducible example of what I'm trying to do:

```
=> \d test1
               Table "public.test1"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 a      | jsonb   |           |          | 
 b      | integer |           |          | 

=> SELECT * FROM test1;
            a             | b  
--------------------------+----
 {"X": 1, "Y": 2}         | 17
 {"X": 4, "Y": 8, "Z": 3} | 22
(2 rows)

=> \ef test1function

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test1function(_item test1)
 RETURNS SETOF text
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
  SELECT jsonb_object_keys(_item.a)
$function$
```

With this setup, I can do queries like so:

```
=> SELECT test1.b, test1.test1function FROM test1;
 b  | test1function 
----+---------------
 17 | X
 17 | Y
 22 | X
 22 | Y
 22 | Z
(5 rows)
```

However, if I try to filter on the test1function field, I don't seem to be able to:

```
=> SELECT test1.b, test1.test1function FROM test1 HAVING test1function = "Z";
ERROR:  column "test1function" does not exist
=> SELECT test1.b, test1.test1function FROM test1 HAVING test1.test1function = "Z";
ERROR:  set-returning functions are not allowed in HAVING
```

**Note**: I am aware that, for this actual example, I could just write something like

```
SELECT b, 'Z' AS test1function FROM test1 WHERE a -> 'Z' IS NOT NULL;
 b  | test1function 
----+---------------
 22 | Z
(1 row)
```

As it happens, though, my actual analogue of `test1function` is more complicated than just a call to `json_object_keys`.

Is it just impossible to filter on the results of something returning SETOF at all?

EDIT: I'm also aware that I can do something like

```
=> SELECT * FROM (SELECT test1.b, test1.test1function FROM test1) q WHERE q.test1function = 'X';
 b  | test1function 
----+---------------
 17 | X
 22 | X
(2 rows)
```

But that's awful... do I *really* have to do a subquery just to give this field a name I can reference?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put set returning functions into the `FROM` clause. If you have to pass a column from a table, you need a lateral join. Then you can reference the columns of the function in the WHERE clause:

```
select *
from test1 t
  cross join lateral test1function(t) as x(item)
where x.item = 'Z';
```

Comment: Seems like if I'm going to have to do a subquery anyway I could just do `SELECT * FROM (SELECT test1.b, test1.test1function FROM test1) q WHERE q.test1function = 'X';` without having to use the `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`.  Or is there a reason I should prefer using that join?